# How can I read data from file to vector?

Tags: c++

So I have this code where an object of class Group has vector with objects from class Student. I am already writing information about the students from the vector into a file but I have problem with reading this information back. How can I do that?

Here is my code so far:

```
class Group
{
private:
string name;
vector <Student*> studentList;

public:
~Group();
Group(void);
Group(string s);
void addStudent(string name,int age,int stNum);
void removeStudent(int stNum);

friend ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Group& g) {
    out << g.name << "\n";
    out << g.studentList.size() << "\n";

        for (unsigned i=0;i<g.studentList.size();i++) {
            out<< g.studentList[i]->getStudentName()<<"\n";
            out<< g.studentList[i]->getStudentAge()<<"\n";
            out<< g.studentList[i]->getStudentNumber()<<"\n"<<endl;
                }
    return out;
    }

friend istream& operator>>(std::istream& in,  Group& g){
    in >> g.name;
        for (unsigned i=0;i<g.studentList.size();i++) {
            //READ DATA FROM FILE
                }
    return in;
            }


};
```

Comment: what is the format of the file data? also read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream

Comment: It is a .txt file

Comment: Looks like you write the file line by line. [Consider using `std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to do the reverse.

Comment: @Fiphe that is a file extension. What does the data in the file actually *look* like? Is it comma separated? Space separated? Is each piece of data on its own line?

Comment: `for (unsigned i=0;i<g.studentList.size();i++)` is needlessly risky. You con't yet know how many entries you could be reading. You could overshoot the end of the file or you could leave some entries in the file. Since `g.studentList.size()` is written to the file, perhaps you should read it back in.

Comment: It occurs to me that you could simplify `Group`'s reading and writing responsibilities by overloading `>>` and `<<` for `Student`.

Comment: The student << and >> are overloaded. How could I use that?

Comment: Side note: `std::vector` is at it's absolute best when it contains things directly rather than pointing to them. There is far less memory management involved and since the data is stored contiguously in the `vector`, there can be orders of magnitude performance improvements.

Comment: `in >> *g.studentList[i]`, but first you would likely have to `new` a `Student` for the pointer to point at. You probably don't want to have to put up with crap like that, though. See above comment. I would ditch pointers entirely and  `Student temp; while (in >> temp) g.studentList.push_back(temp);`

Comment: Just to clarify the previous comments: Replace `vector<Student*>` by `vector<Student>` and replace `g.studentList[i]->` with `g.studentList[i].` accordingly. Then `Student temp; while (in >> temp) g.studentList.push_back(temp);` will work, assuming `operator>>` is correctly overloaded for `Student`. Also if `operator>>` is overloaded in `Student`, then `operator<<` should also be overloaded in it. Why don't you use that in the shown `operator<<` overload?

Comment: How do I change it for <<? Both are overloaded in Student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gathering up the commentary. Note this pushes the hard part, the reading and writing, into `Student` and I left that bit blank. Normally I'd do it because I'm evil, but apparently in this case it is already written.

Major changes:

- No `Student` pointers. Lest memory management overhead and better cache friendliness! By Grabthar's hammer. What a savings.
- `Student` does the `Student` reading and writing.
- `std::vector` handles the element counting so it doesn't need to be stored in and read from the output. Note: This could slow the reading down a little because you can't pre-allocate storage in the `vector`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// note the lack of using namespace std;
// it can be problematic, and especially so in a header.

class Student
{
    //fill in the blanks
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Student& s)
    {
        //fill in the blanks
        return out;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& in, const Student& s)
    {
        //fill in the blanks
        return in;
    }
};

class Group
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::vector<Student> studentList; // death to pointers!

public:
    //~Group(); // Don't need a destructor without the pointer
    Group(void); 
    Group(std::string s);
    void addStudent(std::string name, int age, int stNum);
    void removeStudent(int stNum);
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Group& g)
    {
        out << g.name << "\n";
        //out << g.studentList.size() << "\n"; not necessary. vector handles it.
        for (std::vector<Student>::const_iterator it = g.studentList.cbegin();
             it != g.studentList.cend();
             ++it)
        {
            if (!(out << *it))// let Student's << do all the work
            { // write failed. Might as well stop trying to write.
                break;
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Group& g)
    {
        in >> g.name;
        Student temp;
        while (in >> temp) // let Student's >> do all the work
        {
            g.studentList.push_back(temp);
        }
        return in;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is the for loop from c++11? I get it as a warning. I should not use anything from c++11 Also, now it is crashes when I try to save the group. Before it did not.

Comment: That's a C++11 for loop. Gimme a second and I'll remove it.

Comment: If it crashes on save there is likely something wrong in the `Student` `<<` overload or the pointer is still in play.

Comment: Well, now when not using the c++11 for loop it works.

Comment: Could you explain the for loop because I am not sure what all of the elements there mean?

Comment: How familiar are you with iterators? If the answer's something close to "What's an iterator?" You'd better start with a good text book. Short version: An iterator refers to an item in a container and allows you to move around in the container without having to know anything about the container.

Comment: Here I get an iterator to the beginning of the container (`... it = ... .cbegin()` where the `c` is is there because I need a constant iterator because the container is constant because the `Group` is constant) and I keep advancing the iterator (`++it`) to refer to the next item in the container until I reach the end of the container (`it != ... .cend()`). See how much nicer the C++ 11 syntax is?

Comment: This is the same as `for (int index = 0; index < g.studentList.size(); ++index) { if (!(out << g.studentList[index]) { break; } }`